# Custom Contact Form using Custom Template (Works .. Kind of)

Tags: magento-1.9, contact-form

After a bunch of head scratching, I have finally gotten a custom contact form with additional information on a seperate cms block from the contact form to take the information and send it off, using a custom template that [uses the if statements showed here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946034/mutiple-magento-email-forms-templates) Great! We now have a working contact us form, and a custom other form both using the same template but divying up the different information just like I was hoping.

The trick that allowed me to finally end up successfully sending the email ([explained here](http://www.magentech.com/documentation/fixed-contact-form-not-sending-emails/)) was to change:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
```

to

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl(); ?>contacts/index/post/" id="contactForm" method="post">
```

Not sure if this was a bad hack or what, but it showed success!

The only hitch I am experiencing now, is when submitting the custom cms blocks contact form, the success notification ends up bringing you to the contact us page with the success message. Any ideas why this happens and how it could just be redirected to the current custom cms blocks page with success notification? Thanks!

--- EDIT WITH FILE INFO ---

- app/code/local/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php

Right below the original post function, I have included this;

```
public function postsupportAction()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ( $post ) {
        $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
        /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
        $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
        try {
            $postObject = new Varien_Object();
            $postObject->setData($post);

            $error = false;

            if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['address']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['city']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['state']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['zip']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['country']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['telephone']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            if (Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            if ($error) {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
            /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
            $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->sendTransactional(
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                    null,
                    array('data' => $postObject)
                );

            if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                throw new Exception();
            }

            $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/postsupport');

            return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

    } else {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
}
```

- app/design/frontend/smartwave/legenda/template/contacts/support-form.phtml

`<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl(); ?>contacts/index/postsupport/" id="contactForm" method="post">`

(along with all the inner actual form stuff)
and the final javascript call of:

`<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm', true);
    //]]>
    </script>`

Using all of this sends me to 
`http://website.com/index.php/contacts/index/postsupport/` with a 404 error and no email ever being shot off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are action is **contacts/index/post/** so its going to contacts module on IndexController's post method and if you look at this action your message and redirect is set here so you should create another action here and display your custom message and redirect where you want.for example your function could be

```
 public function customefromAction(){
 //your redirect and messagge//
 }
```

and your action

```
 contacts/index/customefrom/<br>

 //for above to work you have to copy your postAction function content to your action.
```

#### alternative you can submit form using post action and set redirect to your action

around line no 113 you can find:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
```

just comment it

and change

```
$this->_redirect('*/*/'); to
$this->_redirect('*/*/customefrom');// this redirect to your action
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Pawan! Real quick, where would I find the area to add my custom public function denoted in the main answer? That seems like the best method here :)

Comment: copy app\code\core\Mage\Contacts\controllers\IndexController.php to app\code\local\Mage\Contacts\controllers\IndexController.php in this php you can add function

Comment: excellent, thank you! I'll get to work on it and comment if I bump into a problem, but thanks for the answer!

Comment: So I recreated the original post function to  `public function postSupportAction()` and changed the redirect, however the form action `<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl(); ?>contacts/index/support/"` just sends me to 404 of `site.com/index.php/contacts/index/support/` which makes sense since that isn't a page, but neither is `contacts/index/post/` however that works, any idea where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: It should be contacts/index/postsupport  because your  method is postsupportAction

Comment: Thanks for the continued help pawan! I changed the form action to `/postsupport/` instead of support, however it still does the same error with pointing me to a 404 at `site.com/index.php/contacts/index/support/` .. looking in the IndexController, I see `$this->getLayout()->getBlock('contactForm')  ->setFormAction( Mage::getUrl('*/*/post') );` is this something I should repeat for say, `supportForm` and `*/*/supportpost` (it didn't work but could that be on track?

Comment: Can you please share your code with file names and location so i can check what is going wrong .thanks

Comment: Added the files/information, see anything glaringly wrong that I am missing?? (and again thanks for the help!)